# how to pass array of structures from c++ to c#?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm passing structure from c++ to c# this way:

Declare c++ struct:

```
typedef struct _OrderUpdate {
    int32_t instrumentId;
    /* other fields */
} OrderUpdate;
```

Declare c# struct:

```
public struct OrderUpdate2
{
    public int instrumentId;
    /* other fields */
}
```

In c++ declare callback:

```
typedef void (__stdcall * OrderUpdateCallback)(OrderUpdate*);
__declspec(dllexport) void InitializeCallback(long orderUpdateCallbackAddress)

OrderUpdateCallback orderUpdateCallback = (OrderUpdateCallback) orderUpdateCallbackAddress;
```

And use it:

```
OrderUpdate curOrderUpdate;
orderUpdateCallback(&curOrderUpdate);
```

In c# initialize callback and process:

```
[DllImport("NativeAdapter.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern void InitializeCallback(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] OrderUpdateCallback ordersUpdateCallbackPointer)

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void OrderUpdateCallback(ref OrderUpdate2 value);

OrderUpdateCallback orderUpdateCallback = 
            delegate(ref OrderUpdate2 value)
                {
                    // do work
                };

InitializeCallback(orderUpdateCallback);
```

Everything works fine. But now I want to pass array of structures, i.e. not `OrderUpdate` but `OrderUpdate[]`. How can I do that? Will c++ array "map" c# arrays the same way as c++ structures map c# structures? Should I pass array length manually or it can be calculated? How should I update my functions?

probably I can just pass `void*` somehow, then I can spent first 4 bytes for array size and next size * sizeof(OrderUpdate) bytes for data?

Thanks!

**upd:** Another separate question - i don't know how to map arrays even in simplest cases. I can't map array of primitives. For example having such c++ struct:

```
struct orders
{
    signed long long replID; // i8
    signed long long replRev; // i8
    signed long long replAct; // i8
    signed long long id_ord; // i8
    signed int status; // i4
    signed char action; // i1
    signed int isin_id; // i4
    signed char dir; // i1
    char price[11]; // d16.5
    signed int amount; // i4
    signed int amount_rest; // i4
    signed long long id_ord1; // i8
    signed int init_amount; // i4
};
```

how can I map it to c#, i've tried that:

```
public struct Orders
{
    public long replID; // i8
    public long replRev; // i8
    public long replAct; // i8
    public long id_ord; // i8
    public int status; // i4
    public char action; // i1
    public int isin_id; // i4
    public char dir; // i1
    public char price[11]; // d16.5    // compile error
    public int amount; // i4
    public int amount_rest; // i4
    public long id_ord1; // i8
    public int init_amount; // i4
}
```

but i can not declare fixed-size arrays in c#.

Comment: Can you declare the struct array in c# first and then pass a ref of it into the C++ dll?

Comment: why should I pass pointer from c# to c++? In my code i'm passing pointer from c++ to c#.

Comment: I'd answer this question, but there are two distinct questions. I can answer both, but I won't. I'll answer one at a time.

Comment: You give a lot of unnecessary information about callbacks, and finally your question is about structure array marshalling. Asking exactly what you need can improve a chance to get an answer.

Comment: Use the following Marshal class methods: AllocHGlbal, FreeHGlobal, SizeOf, StructureToPtr, PtrToStructure. Declare method parameter as IntPtr, allocate unmanaged memory block of required size, and copy structures to/from this block.

Comment: Second question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba436688-3f16-4cc3-a42c-bca454a61c07/creating-arrays-of-fixed-size-for-pinvoke

Comment: @AlexFarber thanks Alex, probably you can also reference good example of using IntPtr, or I will try myself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i'm sorry sometimes it's hard to understand when there are two questions and when there are one question. sometimes I ask separate questions and people ask to combine them as after all I realize that I asked the same question twice, just different way.

Comment: @AlexFarber in general what is preferred - should I declare parameter as IntPtr and work with unmanaged memory or just declare parameter as structure?

Comment: I always prefer to work with IntPtr and Marshal functions Copy, filling/reading unmanaged memory regions as I need. This gives me full control, like in C.

Comment: Looking at Marshal class (unmanaged memory allocation/deallocation, copy to/from unmanaged memory), and to IntPtr class, which is actually void*, which can be changed by Marshal.SizeOf(some_type) value, you can see that this is enough to handle unmanaged memory. You can do almost everything as in C language.