# AccessViolationException when trying to call c# callback

Tags: c++, pinvoke

I have this simple code:

```
typedef void (__stdcall * OrdersCallback)(ordersTest*);

__declspec(dllexport) void InitializeCallbacks(long ordersCallbackAddress_) {
    OrdersCallback ordersCallbackFunction;
    std::cout << "current ordersCallbackFunction = " << ordersCallbackFunction << " address = " << &ordersCallbackFunction << std::endl;
    std::cout << "set ordersCallbackAddress_ = " << ordersCallbackAddress_ << std::endl;
    ordersCallbackFunction = (OrdersCallback) ordersCallbackAddress_;
    std::cout << "new ordersCallbackFunction = " << ordersCallbackFunction << " address = " << &ordersCallbackFunction << std::endl;

    ordersTest test;
    test.replID = 123;
    std::cout << "use ordersCallbackFunction = " << ordersCallbackFunction << " address = " << &ordersCallbackFunction << std::endl;
    ordersCallbackFunction(&test);
}
```

And when callback is calling AccessViolationException is raised:

```
current ordersCallbackFunction = 000007F92BC354E0 address = 0000009785D1EC68
set ordersCallbackAddress_ = -2043003524
new ordersCallbackFunction = FFFFFFFF863A3D7C address = 0000009785D1EC68
use ordersCallbackFunction = FFFFFFFF863A3D7C address = 0000009785D1EC68

Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I can't understand what's wrong, in another project very similar code works. Thanks!

**upd, more code:**

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void OrdersCallback(ref OrdersTest value);

    [DllImport("CGateNativeAdapter.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern void InitializeCallbacks(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] OrdersCallback ordersSnapshotCallbackPointer);

        OrdersCallback ordersCallback =
            delegate(ref OrdersTest value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("C# Orders call received = " +
                    " replID = " + value.replID);
            };
        InitializeCallbacks(ordersCallback);
```

Comment: Could you show also C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious flaw in what you have shown is that you are attempting to pass the 64 bit pointer as 32 bit value which clearly cannot work. The `ordersCallbackAddress_` parameter is declared as `long`, which is 32 bits wide. But you clearly have a 64 bit process. That almost certainly explains the error that your are experiencing.

Remember that in C++ on Windows, `long` is 32 bits wide. In C# it is 64 bits wide. In any case you should not use integral types to pass pointers. If you have a pointer, design your functions to operate on pointers.

You need to make sure that `ordersCallbackAddress_` is declared to be pointer sized. I don't understand why it is not declared as `OrdersCallback`.

There may be other problems, but you did not show very much code. You did not show struct declarations, or anything on the managed side of the interface.

Comment: absolutely similar code works in another project, for more code refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200194/how-to-pass-array-of-structures-from-c-to-c `long` works fine. I have 64-bit processor

Comment: Do you not believe me that `long` is 32 bits wide in C++ on Windows?

Comment: Doesn't it depend how you build it? (i.e. the target machine in the linker options)

Comment: @doctorlove No. For C++ on Windows, `long` is 32 bits wide.

Comment: thanks I have changed `long` to `long long` and now everything works. But I don't understand how my similar code in another place works. I'm using it in production and it never fails and it uses `long`...

Comment: It will be fine in a 32 bit process. Anyway, I'm sure that you don't want `long long` either. As I said in my answer, you are passing a pointer, so declare it as such. Declare that parameter to be of type `OrdersCallback`. Note that you'll then be able to remove your cast.

Comment: I've used this article and it uses "long" http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/318140/How-to-make-a-callback-to-Csharp-from-C-Cplusplus it works fine on 64 bit processor. sometimes. but not in this case by some reason...

Comment: If you successfully passed a pointer using C++ long on x64 then you ere unlucky. Expect that code to fail at some point. If you use long long then the code is wrong on 32 bit. The right solution is to declare parameter as function pointer. I think I've answered the question.

Comment: also I've found that if my c++ structure contains `char price[11];` and I declare c# structure as `public char[] price` (missing length) then I also have AccessViolationException. arrays should be passed another way.

Comment: Yes indeed. But that's your other question. Which currently contains two questions. As I explained there, I'd happily answer them both. But I cannot do that as it stands because you have squeezed two distinct questions into a single SO question.